# How do I center a textbox inside a panel in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

When I set the textbox's anchor to top,bottom,left,right the textbox still stays on the top. I don't understand, this seems to work for labels and buttons. I kinda need this anchor property for it to adapt well to a form resize.

I'm sorry if I'm missing something incredibly obvious.

Comment: Oh I only need a single line since the textbox will be used for users to enter the quantity of the items they will buy.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want a single line textbox to appear centered vertically and horizontally in your form. Still without showing more than one line. In this case you could set just the Anchor Left and Right property to have you textbox centered horizontally on the form, but for the vertical position you need to work with code adjusting the Iop property of the textbox in the Resize event of the form

For example, after the call to InitializeCompoment of your form you could add the following code to center your textbox (C# but easily convertible to VB.NET)

```
textBox1.Left = 10;
textBox1.Width = yourForm.ClientSize.Width - 20;
textBox1.Top = (yourForm.ClientSize.Height / 2) - yourForm.Height / 2;
textBox1.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right;
```

and then add the event handler for the resize event of your form where you could call again the vertical repositioning of the textbox

```
protected void yourForm_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Top = (this.ClientSize.Height / 2) - textBox1.Height / 2;
}
```